# Involve another field to set function in sequelize-typescript

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

The problem is I can not access other fields which are different type.
In comment column, set function can access to name column but can not access to num column and give undefined when I try to log or use for setDataValue. Is there any solution for this ?

```
 @Column({
    type: DataType.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  })
  name: string;

  @Column({
    type: DataType.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
  })
  num: number;

  @Column({
    type: DataType.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  })

  set comment(value: string) {
    console.log(this.name);
    console.log(this.num);
    console.log(this.getDataValue('name'));
    console.log(this.getDataValue('num'));
    this.setDataValue('comment', value + this.name);
  }
```

This is console output:
test123,
undefined,
test123,
undefined,

Comment: This is very weird, but I guess we are missing more code.

Comment: You need post `Migration` script and, insert or `findOne` script